# Deno web workers - Cannot find name "window"

Tags: deno

I'm trying to run a Deno app with a deno_webview and an http server but for some reason I cannot run both at the same time, calling webview.run() seems to block something and I can no longer reach my http server.

In order to prevent the blocking, I'm trying running either the server or the webview in a webworker, but in both scenarios I get the same error **"Cannot find name 'window'"**

What is the issue here?

**api.webworker.ts**

```
import { Application } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts';
const app = new Application();
await app.listen({ port: 8080 });
```

**webview.webworker.ts**

```
import { WebView } from 'https://deno.land/x/webview/mod.ts';
const webview = new WebView({ url: 'http://localhost:4200' });
await webview.run();
```

**server.ts**

```
const webviewWorker = new Worker(
   './workers/webview.worker.ts', { 
   type: 'module', 
   deno: true 
});
```

Error: [image]

```
const apiWorker = new Worker(
   './workers/api.worker.ts', { 
   type: 'module', 
   deno: true 
});
```

Error: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Workers don't have `window` object, you have to use `self` or `globalThis`

So https://deno.land/x/webview/mod.ts doesn't support being called from a Web Worker.

The library will need to change `window` usage to `globalThis` so it will work int the main process and inside workers.

Comment: Thanks. The author of deno_webview has resolved this issue. https://github.com/eliassjogreen/deno_webview/issues/5  Oak should probably do something about it too but I'm good to go, I only needed one of them to work.